# how to cast byte in javascript like in java?

Tags: javascript, java

in java

```
System.out.println((byte) (31330 >> 4));
```

output : -90

in javascript

```
console.log(31330 >> 4);
```

output : 1958

how to get output `-90` in javascript like cast (byte) in java?

Comment: do  you mean like this
```
console.log(~~(31330 >> 4));
```
it still return 1958

Comment: I don't know how to get the result you're looking for. However, the explanation for this is the fact that JavaScript bit shift operators (`<<` and `>>`) work with signed 32-bit integers. There isn't exactly a `byte` type in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS there's no `byte` type, but we've got "array of bytes", so you can create an array from your expression and then pick the first element:

```js
console.log(new Int8Array([31330 >> 4])[0])
```